# C# dynamic class properties question

Tags: c#, design-patterns, class, dynamic, properties

I have a question regarding the most efficient way to design a class that handles a large number (10K+) of dynamic properties.  Properties only hold boolean or double value types.

I've thought of a couples of answers but not sure if I am on track.

1. Class has one property that passes a hashtable
2. Create class at runtime with properties that represent parent nodes, that can be used to retrieve child classes with child node properties.

Comment: By efficient do you mean fastest at runtime? Or do you mean manageable?

Comment: Well there is no binding done on these properties, so I would say fastest at runtime.

Comment: Do need to hold all 10K in memory? Or will there only be a subset?

Comment: If you have a class in which there are 10k+ dynamic properties, please re-design your architect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I trust that you're not actually talking about properties but a collection of name-value pairs.  That's covered by the Dictionary<> class.  The ExpandoObject class, available in .NET 4.0 is perhaps worth mentioning.

Comment: Initially the class properties were being used as name value pairs - but as the number of properties grows it looks like the Dictionary object may be more efficient.  Thanks